# Queue Effects jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I'm trying to create a queue of animations, I am indicating the order in which I want to run well

```
data-animate-on='{"effect":"slide","queue":2}'
```

Then I read this information on my js, but all are encouraged while

The code is in

> http://jsfiddle.net/ukCUR/

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: The animations are all running at the same time, as I can do to run in the order that I send in "queue": 2